# Why does sails.js ignore /config/env/production.js and use process.env.PORT instead?

Tags: javascript, environment-variables, sails.js, port, environment

I've set the port to 8080 in /config/env/production.js and set the environmental variable NODE_ENV to production.  However, when I lifted sails, I only ever got it to launch at port 8000.  Eventually I realized that I could set the port environmental variable and get the right result, but I'd prefer to use the normal config files.  I have no local.js configuration file, so that's not overwriting.  What am I doing wrong?

```
[15:12:50] nodejs @ myserver : /apps/myapi/
$ cat config/env/production.js
/**
 * Production environment settings
 *
 * This file can include shared settings for a production environment,
 * such as API keys or remote database passwords.  If you're using
 * a version control solution for your Sails app, this file will
 * be committed to your repository unless you add it to your .gitignore
 * file.  If your repository will be publicly viewable, don't add
 * any private information to this file!
 *
 */

module.exports = {

  /***************************************************************************
   * Set the default database connection for models in the production        *
   * environment (see config/connections.js and config/models.js )           *
   ***************************************************************************/

  // models: {
  //   connection: 'someMysqlServer'
  // },

  /***************************************************************************
   * Set the port in the production environment to 80                        *
   ***************************************************************************/

  port: 8080,

  /***************************************************************************
   * Set the log level in production environment to "silent"                 *
   ***************************************************************************/

  // log: {
  //   level: "silent"
  // }

};

[15:13:09] nodejs @ myserver : /apps/myapi/
$ sails lift

Starting app...

Warning: connect.session() MemoryStore is not
designed for a production environment, as it will leak
memory, and will not scale past a single process.
Warning: connect.session() MemoryStore is not
designed for a production environment, as it will leak
memory, and will not scale past a single process.

               .-..-.

   Sails              <|    .-..-.
   v0.11.2             |\
                      /|.\
                     / || \
                   ,'  |'  \
                .-'.-==|/_--'
                `--'-------'
   __---___--___---___--___---___--___
 ____---___--___---___--___---___--___-__

Server lifted in `/apps/myapi`
To see your app, visit http://localhost:8000
To shut down Sails, press <CTRL> + C at any time.

--------------------------------------------------------
:: Thu Oct 15 2015 15:13:21 GMT+0800 (HKT)

Environment : production
Port        : 8000
--------------------------------------------------------
^C
[15:15:20] nodejs @ myserver : /apps/myapi/
$ export PORT=8080

[15:15:41] nodejs @ myserver : /apps/myapi/
$ sails lift

Starting app...

Warning: connect.session() MemoryStore is not
designed for a production environment, as it will leak
memory, and will not scale past a single process.
Warning: connect.session() MemoryStore is not
designed for a production environment, as it will leak
memory, and will not scale past a single process.

               .-..-.

   Sails              <|    .-..-.
   v0.11.2             |\
                      /|.\
                     / || \
                   ,'  |'  \
                .-'.-==|/_--'
                `--'-------'
   __---___--___---___--___---___--___
 ____---___--___---___--___---___--___-__

Server lifted in `/apps/myapi`
To see your app, visit http://localhost:8080
To shut down Sails, press <CTRL> + C at any time.

--------------------------------------------------------
:: Thu Oct 15 2015 15:15:48 GMT+0800 (HKT)

Environment : production
Port        : 8080
--------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Did you change the port on your config/local.js ? Cause it's this one who is use if it's the case

Comment: There is no config/local.js file in this environment.

Comment: Maybe you have a PORT define to 8000 in your system ? Try remove it cause sails take first environment variables. Like you said if you set it to 8080 it's working so maybe it was first define to 8000.  Also try to start sails with sails lift --prod to see witch port is used

Comment: Yeah, you're correct; it just took me a while to find the file that was setting the environmental variable.  I tried unset and it came right back.  If you'd like to add an answer here, I'd be happy to select it (if you want the karma).

Comment: Cool if it's fixed :) no matter the karma ^^  glad to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out there was a .ENV file in the parent directory that was automatically setting the port environment variable (even if I unset it).  I guess it makes sense for sails to respect the environment variable over /config/production.js in this case.